# How to post data in flatlist after pressing button

Tags: react-native, api, post, react-native-flatlist

I have two Text inputs and i want to post data in flatlist after i press a button. How can i make it? And does flatlist update it at the same time?
Also how to sync it on a server to show all users

```
<TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: '#ededed', height: 60 }} value={'name'} />
<TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: '#ededed', height: 60 }} value={'description'} />
```

Comment: Read flat-list documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `state` as `data` to the Flatlist. And then update that `state` on button press. To sync it to the server, you can fire a post request(with the updated `state`) on the same button press.